# SonarQube 6.7.5 - Api to retrieve all rules applied to a project

Tags: sonarqube

I need to compile every rule applied to each of SonarQube's projects.
I could not find a direct way to do this so I am doing the following:

Retrieve the projects. We have over 1000 projects. (Don't ask me why  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

```
http://host/api/components/search?qualifiers=TRK
```

Then I retrieve the languages because if I try to retrieve the Quality Profiles directly without setting the language, I get every profile, even for different languages.

```
http://host/api/measures/component?componentKey=compKey&metricKeys=ncloc_language_distribution
```

After that, I retrieve the Quality profiles

```
http://host/api/qualityprofiles/search?project=projectKey&language=lang
```

Finally, I retrieve the rules

```
http://host/api/rules/search?activation=true&qprofile=profile
```

Now, given the sheer amount of projects and http requests, this process takes a LONG time.
Am I missing an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To know the rules that were applied you need the

- project's languages
- profile used for each language
- rules in each profile

There are a couple different ways to go at this. You've found one. Let's look at others.

(I'm looking at a more recent copy of SonarQube but I believe the APIs in question should still be the same.)

I know that the profiles used in a project's most recent analysis are listed on the homepage. Using the developer console, I see that that data comes in response to a call to `api/navigation/component`. That web service is marked internal, meaning you probably shouldn't use it. So we can't go from project directly to Quality Profile.

However, `api/measures/component` is *not* internal, and with it the front page requests the `ncloc_language_distribution` among other things. That's a `DISTRIB` metric and it gives the project's lines of code per language. For the project I'm looking at, the returned value is `"css=11473;java=235467;js=2549;ts=95516"`. As you see, from there we can get to the languages in the project. Now, let's set that aside for a moment.

Let's say you start by getting the list of Quality Profiles, (`api/qualityprofiles/search`). From that you know which profile is the default for each language. Now use `api/qualityprofiles/projects` to get the list of projects explicitly assigned to each profile. This is probably also a good point to retrieve and store locally the rules per profile.

Now you can iterate your projects, look at the languages for each one and figure out which profiles are used for each project. (Is there an explicit profile assignment for this language? No? Then the default!) Then you can pull your rules-per-profile out of memory and you've got your list for the project.

*dusts hands*
Simple!

Comment: Thanks! Another issue I have is that some of our projects are not associated with any language when fetching them throught the web api. When looking at the web ui, indeed it shows no language associated with if, but there is actually a Quality Profile being associated. For example: I have a Java code project that the meatures/api is not returning java as one of the measures, but looking at sonar's web ui, it shows the java quality profile associated with it.

Comment: Uhm... Not following. Consider opening a thread in the [SonarSource Community](https://community.sonarsource.com). Also, if this solved your problem, you should consider accepting it. :-)

Comment: I will look into it then. About the answer given, it looks like what I said, just worded differently, so I don't believe I should accept it.